# Adjacent polylines subtraction

Tags: qgis, adjacency

I have road segments that have slope values. I want to find the roads with the largest grade changes between neighboring segments.

How do I go about doing that in QGIS?

Comment: can you add a small dataset?

Comment: I recommend reading ['How to ask a good question'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question to include more clarification on your specific problem and describing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

The output is a dynamic table, which you can choose to export if you want to persist the results, and that you can join back to your original road layer.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query

you can add any field from the road layer. The trick is to join the road layer to itself where segments are different (by ID) and where they intersect each others. You can then compute the grade or else.

To avoid computing the grade twice, we compute it only when the 1st segment ID is lower than the 2nd segment ID.

```sql
select a.id, b.id, a.slope, b.slope, abs(a.slope-b.slope) as grade
from  road a
 join road b
  on st_intersects(a.geometry,b.geometry) and a.id < b.id
order by abs(a.slope-b.slope) desc
```